# CMD LDAP error Cannot connect to the LDAP server but connect success by c# code

Tags: windows, ldap, windows-command-prompt

I tried to search and use command line to test connection to LDAP server but it throw error "Cannot connect to the LDAP server" even at my local computer

I use visual studio to debug code at my local computer and it connect successfully?

So How to connect to LDAP serrver using cmd for windows 10?

Cmd error:

```
ldapsearch -x -h LDAP://adserverxx.xx -p 389 -D "cn=ldap,dc=test" -w passxx "objectclass=*"
```

[image]

Code C# [run ok and successfully authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory/499716) by using Visual Studio, run in my local computer (error Network path not found in hosted server)(ASP.NET)

```
bool bSucceeded;
string strAccountId = "ldap";
string strAccountPas = "inxxx";
string strError = "";
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://serveraddxx:389", strAccountId, strAccountPas);
using (DirectorySearcher adsSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry))
{
    //adsSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
    adsSearcher.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + strAccountId + ")";

    try
    {
        SearchResult adsSearchResult = adsSearcher.FindOne();
        bSucceeded = true;

        string strAuthenticatedBy = "Active Directory";
        strError = "User has been authenticated by Active Directory.";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Failed to authenticate. Most likely it is caused by unknown user
        // id or bad strPassword.
        strError = ex.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        directoryEntry.Close();
    }
}
```

P/S: We have problem connect to ldap from our hosted server (web application) today (yesterday it's ok), it only throw exception "Network path not found".

Comment: Please paste the text into the question instead of using an image.

Comment: @RalfFriedl I wrote the command I used before image. Image is posted only to describle error, and add more info that ping and telnet 389 is ok.